# How can I disassociate an account?

Tags: support, linked-accounts, association

I want to disassociate an account from the rest of my associated accounts. How can I do that?

The information in [this answer by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3735/how-to-dissociate-associated-accounts/4212#4212) doesn't seem to be relevant anymore, since I can't find this thing

> Click the "Clear All Associations" button on the bottom of the Accounts page on your profile.

Every time I add or remove an email or OpenID from one site it propagates to the entire network.

Comment: I agree; I can't find the **Clear All Associations** button either. All the same, could you post a screenshot just to avoid confusion?

Comment: This seems hugely relevant now, because the new stackexchanges are getting so varied. I understand that it's possible to create a new account with a new OpenID, but that's headache for the user. I can imagine a lot of people wanting to keep their (professional) SO presence separate from their (personal) parenting.stackexchange presence, for example. Also, when a new site (sexuality?) launches, if users are forced to create new accounts to maintain separation, there won't be the usual crowd of 100-rep users at the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accounts are now network level, and have been for a bit.  It hasn't been blogged, but just due to timing constraints.

[image]

Behold, the new login management screen.  This solves a long standing complaint about how complicated managing credentials across multiple Stack Exchange sites was.

Since all associations are done through credentials, disassociating* doesn't really make sense anymore.  It's roughly equivalent to "delete this account", as removing the "associating credentials" would leave the user unusable.

So, in short, it is no longer possible to disassociate accounts.

<sub>*The associate button is still available for debugging purposes, it will be going away eventually.</sub>

Comment: So would [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3735/162705) now be marked **status-declined**?

Comment: @Chris - delete probably, it *was* correct at the time.  Maybe obsolete?  We don't have a lot of precedent for "technically, this no longer makes sense".

Comment: I don't get it - There are many cases of users asking to disassociate accounts, but now it's not possible at all. Can this not even be done on request?

Comment: This is kind of annoying.  I've got sites I'd like to disassociate just because I don't like them always being at the top of the "all sites" list when I'm navigating via the stack exchange dropdown.

Comment: Disassociating still makes sense and is clear from a user perspective - it's just likely harder to implement now.  The desire is that others see your accounts as separate when you choose to make it so.  That is independent of credential related issues.

Comment: I hate to bring up an old subject, but regarding what Steve said in his comment, is this not requestable via contact with the SE team? I want to separate my personal accounts from my professional SO account, without losing the questions and answers I have already made... If it's not at all possible I'll create a work-only account anyway and deal, but is there any way at all?