# Is it possible to disconnect related stack exchange accounts?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, user-accounts, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disassociate an account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109044/how-can-i-disassociate-an-account)

I have signed to **multiple** stack exchange sites. I've used google account as my open ID. As a result, I have all accounts linked with single profile. Now let's say I have a need to change my nick for some of the accounts or I want to **separate** them, so that there would be no direct link between my user profiles.

A use case when I want my stack overflow activity to be visible to the employer, but I wouldn't like my private activity to be easily connected with me on philosophical/religious sites.

The accounts already exists and there are questions/answers on them already, so the desired effect would be to separate them, not to simply create second identity.

Is such action possible, and if so, how to achieve that?