# Can I Separate Currently Related Accounts For Separate Sites?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

Currently, I have accounts on a few different SE sites. Which is great- But I realized that I use one for work, and I want it separated from my personal accounts.

Is there a way that I can disassociate my Stack Overflow account from my other accounts? I understand if I do, I may lose my 100 point association bonus from Arqade, but that doesn't bother me all that much. I use Stack Overflow for learning purposes, not to have the most rep ever.

Comment: This didn't show up for some reason in my searches the past few days, but I found the answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109044/how-can-i-disassociate-an-account