# How can you change your privacy settings?

Tags: support, privacy

hmmm...A friend of mine accidentally knows about my Stack Overflow username, but I don't want him to see all past questions. Is there a way that I can hide myself from the public (i.e., like Facebook)?

I looked around but couldn't find anything.  I can hide my communities, but it looks like my questions are still around...in public

Comment: If user name is the problem, you can change it on all sites, and hope your friend didn't save your profile URL anywhere.

Comment: @Shadow Another option would be [disassociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109044/269301). It's not perfectly clear from that link, but it's possible to have one of your accounts separated from your main account if for some reason you no longer want to be associated with the content of that account. That account will then become an anonymous user.

Comment: @Mast no that's not an option... think you missed the end of the answer? "it is no longer possible to disassociate accounts"

Comment: @Shadow The answer is incorrect, I've recently dissociated one of my accounts so I know for a fact it's still possible. Just a bit more hoop-jumping. Think I've done that by using [Contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: @Mast the answer is correct, it talks about a button that was present in ancient times as far as I remember.

Comment: @Shadow Technically that makes the answer partly correct. It's possible but not the way it used to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely ask questions [anonymously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89248/302377). However, hiding content from a specific user defeats the whole purpose of the site, which promotes open learning and knowledge sharing. So, such localized privacy settings aren't available here.

So, the solution to your problem would be to ask questions anonymously in the future. However, your existing questions cannot be hidden from any particular user, but can be anonymized for all users.

Comment: Do note that sites like The Workplace often deal with users using a throw-away account for exactly this reason: staying anonymous.