# My accounts were not deleted. What happened?

Tags: support, users, user-accounts, deleted-accounts, account-recovery

Because of personal reasons, 10 days ago I requested that all my accounts be deleted. I followed the guidelines [from this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account) but it didn't generate any result; all my accounts are still active.

At this point I don't know if my request is stuck in the tubes somewhere, waiting or ...

So, can anyone explain the process for deleting users (who themselves demand the deletion) and how much time it usually takes? e.g.

1. Are the users deleted as soon as Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange has the manpower to do so, or is it an automatic process?
2. If you interact with Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange after you request the deletion, is the deletion cancelled?
3. Does the deletion account for the possibility a user might have had a bad day and decided to end it, but just in case do the delete later on (after weeks, months, etc.) in case maybe the user has a change of heart (recovery will [be a pain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115656/when-an-account-is-deleted-how-much-of-personal-data-is-retained-about-the-accou) if deletion is done and the user wishes he could get his account back)?

... this sort of stuff... Basically, what's the process?

Answer (score 13):

Your emails ended up in the spam folder. I've responded to them now.

To answer your other questions:

1. We usually ask for confirmation if you have a large amount of activity on the site. This may seem excessive, given the amount of pre-preparation required, but a lot of users don't quite realize what profile deletion means on SE (if you're used to, say, Facebook's "deletion", you might think you can come back and re-activate your account at some point, or that it involves removing all of your posts - but generally-speaking, neither of these are true.)
2. No. You could theoretically keep on posting right up until we click the big red DELETE button.
3. See #1: we make it an intentionally tedious process, because there's no easy undo and folks *do* sometimes ask for it without realizing what it means.

Comment: Thanks! I will respond to that mail. Just one other question. I sent 2 emails (one for Programmers and one for SO and meta.SO). Is it enough to reply to the mail I've just received and include all my user URLs there?

Comment: Yeah, that'll do just fine.

Comment: I've sent the confirmation e-mail. Thanks!

Comment: @yoda: well, like I said, there's no path to recovery, and plenty of folks don't understand what deletion entails - I've seen all too many folks who start out to "ragequit" assuming this involves removing all of their questions or answers. "Down-vote me, eh? I'll show you!" If the former ever changes (and I wouldn't mind seeing, say, a "staging period" where deletion merely hides the account details), then self-deletion would make more sense. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67415/users-should-be-able-to-close-accounts-on-specific-se-sites-without-developer-mo

Answer (score 6):

> - are the users deleted as soon as SO/SE has the manpower to do so

Yes, and given that it's the holidays I guess the team's just busy. I'd suggest waiting a while.

> - if you interact with SO/SE after you request the deletion is the deletion cancelled

I thought you wanted your account deleted, why would you still use it? I'm confused. It might confuse the team as well.

> - does the deletion account for the possibility a user might have had a bad day and decided to end it, but just in case do the delete later on (after weeks, months etc) in case maybe the user has a change of hart (recovery will be a pain if deletion is done and the user wishes he could get his account back)?

Jeff is known to dislike ragequits, but generally I'd say no. If you ask for your account to be deleted be prepared for the fact that it will go away permanently.

If you're having second thoughts *turn back now while you still have time*.

Comment: I interacted with Meta to place a comment on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115656/when-an-account-is-deleted-how-much-of-personal-data-is-retained-about-the-accou). I removed the comment today and asked this question instead. I do want my accounts deleted.